# Dynamic heading and table cells in php

Tags: php

I have a problem doing a dyanamic table

My table structure is below:

```
======================================================================
tender_id | coc | datasheet | datecode | shelflife | Suppliername
======================================================================
   201    |  No |   Yes      |     Yes  |     No   |  Supplier1
   201    | Yes |   No       |     Yes  |     No   |  Supplier2
   201    | No  |   No       |     No   |     No   |  Supplier3
```

My expected result in PHP is

```
=============================================
 COC | Datasheet | Date Code | Supplier Name
=============================================
   -     Yes          Yes       Supplier1
  Yes    -            Yes       Supplier2
```

The results should only show if the value is 'Yes'. Even the heading should not be shown if all the values are 'No'. For example in the above condition shelflife value is 'No' for all the suppliers. In this case even the heading it should not show. I have tried some script, but there is some problem.

This is the script i tried:

```
$sql_shelf = "SELECT tender_id, suppliername, coc, date_code, shelf_life , datasheet FROM comparitive_statement1 WHERE (coc='Yes' OR technical_compliance='Yes' OR date_code='Yes' OR shelf_life='Yes' OR datasheet='Yes') tender_id='$tender_id' group by suppliername";

    $result = mysql_query($sql_shelf) or die($sql_shelf."<br/><br/>".mysql_error());
    $i = 0;
    while ($list = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    if($i == 0){
    echo '<tr>';
    $sh = $list['shelf_life'];
    if ($sh=="No") {
    } else {
    echo '<td><b>Shelf Life</b></td>';
    }
      echo '</tr>';
      $i++;
      }

    echo '<tr>';
    $sl1 = $list['shelf_life'];
    if ($sl1=="No") {
    } else {
    echo "<td>{$list['shelf_life']}</td>";\
    echo "</tr>";
    }
     ++$i;
     }
```

The script is bit long, so i have just put the records related to shelflife.

Comment: Please also add the SQL statement that you're already written. Is it stored in `$sql_shelf`?

Comment: If you want to hide a full column, including the header, then you will either need save your returned rows in a php array and then filter that array **OR** use javascript to check the columns and filter/hide.

Comment: Why is Supplier3 not part of your output?

Comment: Try to write with proper if() statement. You can write if ($sl1!="No") if you have Boolean value stored in $sl1 variable.

Comment: @mapek. i have edited the question with the sql query. yes it is stored in $sql_shelf.

Comment: @maxhb it looks like `Supplier3` is omitted as all the column values are `No`

Comment: @maxhb. Its not showing supplier3 because all the values are 'No'. You can see my table structure

Comment: please use query to reduce this data set condition like select * from table_name where coc ="yes" or datasheet = "yes" or datacode = "yes" or shelflife = "yes" using this your firstly your last row reduced autometically

Comment: Have you already tried to add `... AND (coc = 'Yes' OR datasheet = 'Yes' OR datecode = 'Yes' OR  shelflife = 'Yes')` to your SQL statement?

Comment: @ Jileshb. i tried in my php code, but it was not working. Let me try in the sql query

Comment: @Mapek, Let me try that now. I will let u know

Comment: yes first do this in your sql query it will removes all rows where this 4 column value is No

Comment: or please can you edit your post and put your query

Comment: Two questions: 
1) Can't you update your query to select only those records who have datecode = 'Yes'?

2) Can't you use mysql_num_rows() http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php to determine if your result have any rows? Go ahead with printing header and table only if mysql_num_rows() returns > 0.

Comment: @Jilesh. I have edited the question with the  latest query. Its working fine, but i have an issue. if the first row any field value is 'No' then the heading is not appearing. For example, in my table structure first row 'coc' value is 'No'. So its just emitting the heading of COC. What can be done?

Comment: you need result like you define in your expected result ? right ? if all column value is no than and than that column not display right ? otherwise display - in that column

Comment: @Jilesh. Yes very true. For example, in my table structure first row 'coc' value is 'No'. So its just emitting the heading of COC. But in the second row coc is 'Yes' which means the heading COC must be shown. Am i clear?

Comment: but its not showing the heading 'COC'

Answer (score 0):

In order to determine whether or not an entire column should display, you're going to need to first iterate through all records. I've not debugged the following, but hopefully if it doesn't work it will be enough to give you an idea of what needs to be done:

```
$result = mysql_query($sql_shelf) or die($sql_shelf."<br/><br/>".mysql_error());
$stuff = array(); //an array for all of the rows
$columns = array(); //an array for the columns
while ($list = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $stuff[] = $list; //add list to the appropriate array
    if(empty($columns)) { foreach($list as $key=>$val) { $columns[$key] = 0; } } //fill $columns with a dynamic number of 0s based on how many columns the database returns
    foreach($list as $key=>$val) { if(!is_numeric($val) && $val!= 'No') { $columns[$key] = 1; } } //sets column array value to 1 for any non-numeric/non-no answer
}
//now we actually build the table
echo "<table><thead>";
echo "<tr>";
foreach($columns as $name=>$display){
    if($display== 1) { echo "<th>".$name."</th>"; } //if we set the value earlier to 1, then we want the column to show
}
echo "</tr></thead><tbody>";
foreach($stuff as $list){
    echo "<tr>";
        foreach($list as $key=>$val){
            if($columns[$key] == 1){ echo "<td>".$val."</td>";
        }
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</tbody></table>";
```

Edit: Added table tags

Comment: Complete table is disoriented. But iam able to view the records. Can you pls tell me where should i start a <table> and where will i end it</table> also can i put my own headings?

Comment: In order to use your own headings, you're going to need an array similar to: $columnnames['Suppliername'] = 'Supplier Name'; and then modify echo "<th>".$name."</th>"; to be echo "<th>".$columnnames[$name]."</th>";